# How to show child terms of the selected Parent in wp custom Taxonamy

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have created a custom post type: "Publication" and its taxonomy "publication-genre"

using the taxonomy Selected I am displaying the post related to it using the isotope js.

I have converted the taxonomy in the dropdown and based on the selections I am able to display my posts.

Now My questions are: 
For example :(parent and its child terms)

```
1. Vision
    a. Vision 1
    b. vision 2 
2. View 
     a. View 1 
     b. View 2
```

If the Terms "vision" is selected then in the other dropdown which consists of child terms should show a child of only the parent term selected not others.

**For getting all Child Term :**

```
foreach( get_terms( 'publication-genre', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 ) ) as $parent_term ) { 
     foreach( get_terms( 'publication-genre', array( 'child_of' => $terms[0],'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $parent_term->term_id ) ) as $child_term ) {
       echo "<option value='.".$child_term->slug."'>" . $child_term->name . "</option>\n";
      }
}

?>
```

**For getting Parent Term :**

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_terms("publication-genre", array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 )); 
        $count = count($terms);
        if ( $count > 0 ){  
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
        echo "<option value='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</option>\n";
        }
    } 
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the current term_id and check if current term_id is equal to parent and child term id

```
//get current the term_id    
 $publication_genre_category_object=get_queried_object();
 $publication_genre_current_term_id = $publication_genre_category_object->term_id;

        foreach( get_terms( 'publication-genre', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 ) ) as $parent_term ) { 
             foreach( get_terms( 'publication-genre', array( 'child_of' => $terms[0],'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $parent_term->term_id ) ) as $child_term ) {
                 if($publication_genre_current_term_id  == $child_term->term_id)
                 {
                     $child_term_selected = "selected";
                 }
               echo "<option value='.".$child_term->slug."' ".$child_term_selected.">" . $child_term->name . "</option>\n";
              }
        }
         $terms = get_terms("publication-genre", array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 )); 
            $count = count($terms);
            if ( $count > 0 ){  
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
             if($publication_genre_current_term_id  == $term->term_id)
             {
                 $term_selected = "selected";
             }
            echo "<option value='.".$term->slug."' ".$term_selected.">" . $term->name . "</option>\n";
            }
        }
```